# Compare strings from a txt with bash or python ignoring pattern

Tags: python, string, bash, search, compare

I want to search a txt file for the duplicate lines excluding [p] and the extension in the comparison. Once the equal lines are identified, show only the line that does not contain [p] and with its extension. I have this lines in **test.txt**:

```
Peliculas/Desperados (2020)[p].mp4
Peliculas/La Duquesa (2008)[p].mp4
Peliculas/Nueva York Año 2012 (1975).mkv
Peliculas/Acoso en la noche (1980) .mkv
Peliculas/Angustia a Flor de Piel (1982).mkv
Peliculas/Desperados (2020).mkv
Peliculas/Angustia (1947).mkv
Peliculas/Días de radio (1987) BR1080[p].mp4
Peliculas/Mona Lisa (1986) BR1080[p].mp4
Peliculas/La decente (1970) FlixOle WEB-DL 1080p [Buzz][p].mp4
Peliculas/Mona Lisa (1986) BR1080.mkv
```

In this file lines 1-6 and 9-11 are the same (withouth ext and [p]). Output needed:

```
Peliculas/Desperados (2020).mkv
Peliculas/Mona Lisa (1986) BR1080.mkv
```

i try this but only shows the same lines deleting extension and pattern [p] but i dont know the correct line and I need the entire line complete

`sed 's/\[p\]//' ./test.txt | sed 's\.[^.]*$//' | sort | uniq -d`

Error output (missing extension):

```
Peliculas/Desperados (2020)
Peliculas/Mona Lisa (1986) BR1080
```

Answer (score 0):

because you mentioned bash...

Remove any line with a `p`:

```
cat test.txt | grep -v p                     
home/folder/house from earth.mkv
home/folder3/window 1.avi
```

Remove any line with `[p]`:

```
cat test.txt | grep -v '\[p\]'
home/folder/house from earth.mkv
home/folder3/window 1.avi
home/folder4/little mouse.mpg
```

Not likely your need, but just because: Remove `[p]` from every line, then dedupe:

```
cat test.txt | sed 's/\[p\]//g' | sort | uniq
home/folder/house from earth.mkv
home/folder/house from earth.mp4
home/folder2/test.mp4
home/folder3/window 1.avi
home/folder3/window 1.mp4
home/folder4/little mouse.mpg
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you can use `itertools.groupby` with a function that makes a key that consists of the filename without any `[p]` and with the extension removed.

For any groups of size 2 or more, any filenames not containing '[p]' are printed.

```
import itertools
import re

def make_key(line):
    return re.sub(r'\.[^.]*$', '', line.replace('[p]', ''))

with open('test.txt') as f:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in f]

for key, group in itertools.groupby(lines, make_key):
    files = [file for file in group]
    if len(files) > 1:
        for file in files:
            if '[p]' not in file:
                print(file)
```

This gives:

```
home/folder/house from earth.mkv
home/folder3/window 1.avi
```

Comment: it works with this example but with my final file it doesn't work. Returns results that do not have duplicate lines with [p]. I do not know why. My txt has 12 thousand lines

Comment: @Sirfrancis18 Please give an example of what it is doing differently from what you require, so that I can understand your requirements better.

Comment: I attach a partial of my file. In this file only files 1-6 and 9-11 are equal with q and ext different. https://file.io/yDMd0qfA

Comment: I Dont see why dont work. The estructure is the same

Comment: @Sirfrancis18 Your link is giving a 404 and anyway the example output is as important as the lines themselves. Please edit the question to state **exactly** the criteria for: (a) how to decide what is considered a "duplicate", and (b) which filenames should be printed and which should be excluded. If you do that, and then add a comment here to alert me to it, then hopefully I will look next time.

Comment: Sorry by my mistake. I edit the question. Thanks for the help

Comment: `return re.sub(r'\..*?$',`   error with lines have more than 1 "."  . Whit this work better `\.[^.]*$`

Comment: @Sirfrancis18 Okay I'll try to look when I have time. By the way, regarding lines with more than one `.` - this was the intention behind the `?` is in the regexp - so that `.*?` matches as few characters as possible (as `*?` is a lazy rather than greedy quantifier). However, for some reason it still seems to include the characters from an earlier `.` unnecessarily, and I'm not sure I understand exactly why, so yes, I think that your suggestion is a good one, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If a 2-pass solution (which reads the `test.txt` file twice) is acceptable, would you please try:

```
declare -A ary                          # associate the filename with the base
while IFS= read -r file; do
    if [[ $file != *\[p\]* ]]; then     # the filename does not include "[p]"
        base="${file%.*}"               # remove the extension
        ary[$base]="$file"              # create a map
    fi
done < test.txt

while IFS= read -r base; do
    echo "${ary[$base]}"
done < <(sed 's/\[p\]//' ./test.txt | sed 's/\.[^.]*$//' | sort | uniq -d)
```

Output:

```
Peliculas/Desperados (2020).mkv
Peliculas/Mona Lisa (1986) BR1080.mkv
```

- In the 1st pass, it reads the file line by line to create a map which associates the filename (with an extension) with the base (w/o the extension).
- In the 2nd pass, it replace the output (base) with the filename.

If you prefer 1-pass solution (which will be faster), please try:

```
declare -A ary                  # associate the filename with the base
declare -A count                # count the occurrences of the base
while IFS= read -r file; do
    base="${file%.*}"           # remove the extension
    if [[ $base =~ (.*)\[p\](.*) ]]; then
                                # "$base" contains the substring "[p]"
        (( count[${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}]++ ))
                                # increment the counter
    else
        (( count[$base]++ ))    # increment the counter
        ary[$base]="$file"      # map the filename
    fi
done < test.txt

for base in "${!ary[@]}"; do    # loop over the keys of ${ary[@]}
    if (( count[$base] > 1 )); then
                                # it duplicates
        echo "${ary[$base]}"
    fi
done
```

Comment: 2-pass solution worked. The other Dont. I Dont know why

Comment: @Sirfrancis18 thank you for the feedback. I don't know why either :-/. Which is your bash version? Please enjoy the 2-pass solution anyway.